# Best way for value and type handling for preparing SQL Table Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a class which represents a dynamic table which is going to be created in a sql database.

```
public class DynamicTable
{
      public List<DynamicField> fieldNames { get; set; }
}
```

The DynamicField represents a pair of the field name and it's dataType:

```
public class DynamicField
    {
        public Type type {get;set;}
        public String fieldName {get;set;}

 public DynamicField(String fieldName, Type datatype)
        {
           this.fieldName = fieldName;
           this.type = datatype; 
        }

}
```

My worries are about, that you could pass any Type you want but I would only need some specific datatypes like String, int, date,float.

How could I improve my code, that it's only possible to pass them?
Based on the idea to use the attribute type to correctly create the table in my sql database, is there a better way than using the System.Type type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could put a constraint with Generic, like below. But I also guess it will be quite unusable in your dynamic scenario ( and it won't accept nullable types)

```
public class DynamicField
{
    public String fieldName { get; set; }
    private Type _type;

    public DynamicField SetFieldType<T>() where T:struct
    {
        this._type = typeof(T);
        return this;
    }

    public Type GetFieldType()
    {
        return this._type;
    }

    public DynamicField(String fieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
}
```

You could then write something like :

```
   var t = new DynamicTable();
   t.Add(new DynamicField("ColumnA").SetFieldType<String>());
```

Maybe you could just check in the `type` setter that `value.IsValueType` is true, and throw an exception if false.

Hope this will help,

Comment: how would I set the type if I would make an instance of the DynamicField class?

Comment: @Zteve : Updated my code so than I can provide some kind of "fluent" example. Outside of that, dynamic scenario would be in a switch/if statement, which makes me say it is quite unusable in your scenario (and just moves the problem).